# Is there a way to convert a Javolution Struct object to json using Gson/Jackson?

Tags: java, gson, javolution

I have tried to use Gson to create a json object from Javolution Struct object. It gives errors because Javolution Struct object is not a regular POJO.

Is there a way to do it or it cant be done?

**[Edit 1]: Errors**

```
Exception in thread "dv-1-1" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner.next accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.ref" to unnamed module @22dd58ca
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:349)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:349)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:582)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:561)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:516)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:496)
```

Comment: Some code and the error you get from Gson might help answering.

Comment: @pirho see the errors. I think this has to do with how Javolution lib works where the object is saved in bytes and not POJO. I just want to see if someone else has looked at converting Struct to json object.